# Electric mystery

Tags: electrical

Wondering what this is for doesn’t look up to code to me idk what to do with it [image]

Comment: what do you mean by `what this is` ?

Comment: Will need to find if those capped wires still have power and where they go.  Either put them in a box with a cover or remove them from the panel and abandon/remove them.

Comment: What was there previously?  I'm sure it hasn't always been that way with an open hole in the wall and a metal box connector hanging out with wires attached.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.